# Question about sensitivity analysis of an LP problem. Range for the dual be unfeasible.

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

Let an LP of the form:

$\max \ ax_1+x_2$

$s.t. \ -x_1+x_2 \leq 3$

$\ -bx_1+x_2\leq6$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x_1,x_2\geq0$

**For which range of values of $a$ and $b$ we have an unfeasible dual problem?**

I know that the primal problem should be unbounded in order to the dual problem be unfeasible, but I dont know how to go any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let's write down the dual:

$$\min 3p_1 + 6p_2$$

$$-p_1-bp_2 \geq a$$

$$p_1+p_2 \geq 1$$

$$p_1, p_2 \geq 0$$

This is a $2$ dimensional problem, draw out the domain of dual and check if it is feasible.

Comment: ok, but thinking about, say, 4-dimensional problem. How can I solve this algebraically, please?

Comment: Simplex method? Fourier-Motzkin elimation?